# Vue component can load message.user but not message.user.name

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make a realtime chat in Laravel using Vue and Pusher.
I already have done everything but I can´t understand why my component ChatMessages.vue can show {{ message.user }} where I can see that the user has a name but it can´t show {{ message.user.name }}.

Example:

```
{{ message.user }}
```

Here are the results

[image: Here are the results]

```
{{ message.user.name }}
```

Here are the results

[image: Here are the results]

This is my code:

ChatMessages.vue

```html
<template>
<ul class="chat">
    <li class="left clearfix" v-for="message in messages">
        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">
                    {{ message.user.email }}
                </strong>
            </div>
            <p>
                {{ message.message }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['messages'],

    mounted(){
        console.log(this.messages)
    }
  };
</script>
```

ChatForm.vue

```html
<template>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="message.message" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendMessage">
            Send
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],

    data() {
        return {
            message:{
                message: ' ',
                user: this.user
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            this.$emit('messagesent', this.message)

            this.message = {}
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

App.js

```js
Vue.component('chat-messages', 
require('./components/ChatMessages.vue').default);
Vue.component('chat-form', require('./components/ChatForm.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
    messages: []
},

mounted() {
    this.fetchMessages();
    Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
        this.messages.push({
            message: e.message.message,
            user: e.user
        });
    });
},

methods: {
    fetchMessages() {
        axios.get('/chat/messages').then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;
        })
    },

    addMessage(message) {
        this.messages.push(message);

        axios.post('/chat/messages', message).then(response => {
            //console.log(response.data);
        })
    }
}
});
```

The view

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>HelpEachOthers</title>

<!-- Bulma CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" />

<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chats</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <chat-messages :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <chat-form v-on:messagesent="addMessage" user="{{ Auth::user() }}"></chat-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is only happening in new messages that are sent after the page has loaded. The messages that were in the database when the component is mounted are displayed with the correct name tag.
For test this I have 2 chrome windows with 2 differentes users. In the windows where I am sending the message I can´t see the name but in the other window with other user I can see the name in realtime, without reloading.

Comment: What does `Auth::user()` return? If it's some sort of JSON object, shouldn't you be binding the `user` prop attribute, ie `v-bind:user="{{ Auth::user() }}"`?

Comment: If I understood you, if I have a conversation between a few users all messages will have the name of the authenticated user in his session instead of having the name of the autor of the message. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be passing the `user` prop as a JSON **string**. For example, if you were to view your page source, you would see something like...

> ```
> <chat-form ... user="&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,..."
> ```

In order to make it an object with properties you can access (like `.name`, `.email`, etc), you need to **bind** the attribute value, eg

```
<chat-form v-on:messagesent="addMessage" 
           v-bind:user="{{ Auth::user() }}">
</chat-form>
```

You can also use the [`v-bind` shorthand syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand), eg

```
:user="{{ Auth::user() }}"
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props

Comment: Thats it, sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the answer but my first troubleshooting suggestion would be to check the e.user type value (e.g String or Object) inside of App.js (mounted method).

Hard to say without spinning up a local env but I’m thinking that value is a JSON string, not a JS object.

If the value is of data type string, you can probably convert it to an object using JSON.parse(e.user)

Good luck!

Comment: Same issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: Interesting. What’s the output of the below look like? console.log(e, typeof e.user)

Comment: {message: {…}, user: {…}} "object"

Comment: And just for sanity sake, console.log(e.user.name)?

Comment: Test1, the current name of the user. The thing is that in the chrome window where I sent the message I cannot see tha user.name. But in other chrome windows I can see the user.name in real time, without reload.

Comment: Gotcha. Inside of ChatForm, can you console out the value of user inside of a mounted method?

Comment: {"id":1,"name":"Test","email":"test@example.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2019-01-01 21:52:48","updated_at":"2019-01-01 21:52:48"}

Comment: I think we’ve found it. Inside of sendMessage (ChatfForm) you’re resetting this this.message object to {}. Instead it should be set to { message:’’, user: this.user }

Comment: Nice try, same issue. We are missing something.